# How put labels over stacked bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I am following the explanation mentioned [here](https://rpubs.com/escott8908/RGC_Ch3_Gar_Graphs) about how to put labels in the middle of a stacked bar chart.
The labels are put on the right spots, but the bar chart is completely been shrunken. What am I doing wrong here?

When running this script without the labeling, it looks okay.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(variable = c("name", "name", "name", "name", "name"
), score = structure(1:5, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    N = c(97, 82, 116, 131, 116), percentage = c(18, 15, 21, 
    24, 21)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("variable", 
"score", "N", "percentage"))

df <- ddply(df,"variable ", mutate, label=cumsum(percentage) - .5*percentage)

ggplot(as.data.frame(df),aes(x = variable , y = percentage, fill = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill')+
  #geom_text(aes(y=label,label=N), color='black') +
   coord_flip()
```

But if adding the labels, it doesn't look good at all:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(df),aes(x = variable , y = percentage, fill = score)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'fill')+
  geom_text(aes(y=label,label=N), color='black') +
   coord_flip()
```

Comment: try removing `postion = "fill"`

Comment: Thanks! It workst perfectly now.